# which players are used in vine app to play videos in android

Tags: java, android, video-streaming, sbt-android-plugin

I would like to play videos to play videos in my android app like vine app.
I have all the urls of videos like " http://swytchboard.s3.amazonaws.com/Videos/102_1378616771.mp4 ".

How to play these videos efficiently.

Thanks to all in advance, Have a happy coding.

Comment: Did you find a solution for your issue? I'm facing the same problem! any idea?